# iOS Keyboard Dismisses after one keystroke after having tapped SearchBar

Tags: ios

Can someone help? I just can't seem to figure out what is happening.

My app shows a list of books. I have a SearchBar that allows you to search the books. The problem is that when I tap the search bar, the keyboard comes up as it should, but when I hit the first key, the letter is registered in the search bar, but the keyboard promptly closes. Once I hit the search bar again, the keyboard opens, but this time I'm able to type in a full query. I don't understand why it closes after the first key is pressed.

Here is the code to the search bar:

```
struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var text: String
var placeholder: String
var onSearchButtonClicked: () -> Void

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISearchBar {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
    searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    return searchBar
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = text
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
    var parent: SearchBar
    var searchWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?

    init(_ parent: SearchBar) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        parent.text = searchText
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        parent.text = searchBar.text ?? ""
        searchWorkItem?.cancel()
        let workItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak searchBar] in
            searchBar?.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        searchWorkItem = workItem
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: workItem)
        parent.onSearchButtonClicked()
    }
}
```

}

I reference it in the book page with this:

```
      List {
            Section(header: SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Search", onSearchButtonClicked: performSearch)) {
                if searchText.isEmpty {
                    ForEach(books) { book in
                        BookRow(book: book)
                            .onAppear {
                                if book == books.last && !isLoading {
                                    isLoading = true
                                    fetchBooks(query: selectedGenre)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    ForEach(searchResults) { book in
                        BookRow(book: book)
                            .onAppear {
                                if book == searchResults.last && !isLoading {
                                    isLoading = true
                                    searchBooks(query: searchText, startIndex: searchResults.count)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Bookshelf")
        .background(Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2))
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .onAppear {
            fetchBooks(query: selectedGenre)
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                Picker(selection: $selectedPickerIndex, label:
                                        Text(genres[selectedPickerIndex])) {
            ForEach(0 ..< genres.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(genres[index]).tag(index)
            }
        }
                            
            .onChange(of: selectedPickerIndex) { value in
                if value == 0 {
                    selectedGenre = "Fantasy+Science+Fiction"
                } else {
                    selectedGenre = genres[value].lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
                }
                books.removeAll()
                fetchBooks(query: selectedGenre)
            }
        )
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .overlay(
        Group {
            if isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Maybe the Section part is reloaded for some reasons like having a condition to display it. Can you also provide the rest of the code?
Also the part to fetch books seems a bit off, but can't really tell from this snippet. I would move that in a `.onChange(of: searchText, perform: { newValue in fetchBooks(query: selectedGenre) })` added to the main View (note: if fetchBooks  uses searchText, you have to pass newValue to fetchBooks and shouldn't use searchText directly) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)

Comment: Thanks for responded, I updated the code.

Comment: I tested the SearchBar component with a simple project and it seems ok. I don't see anything strange which is closing the keyboard in the View file, sorry. As an improvement I still suggest to move all the logic to fetch or search books in the `.onChange` method under `.onAppear` of the List. For the bug you may try to place a lot of breakpoints to see where in the code the keyboard is closing.

Comment: OK thanks Kazikal. I'll take a look on the on Appear. I was using a different method with a different text box and it worked, but it was creating a whole host of other problems. Mostly stylistic.